# Add string of (variable number of) arguments to a function within a function

Tags: r, function, arguments

Let's say I have a function that creates *x* number of objects based on the length of an input variable. I then want those *x* number of objects to be used as arguments in a function I supply to my function. Assumign that my number of arguments is variable (based on the number of argument names provided), how can I do this?

Can I do this via a string of argument names perhaps?

A non-working example to illustrate what I'm asking:

(in this case, using arguments created outside the function to simplify the example):

```
foo <- 1:5
na.rm <- T
func <- mean

f1 <- function(func,arg.names) { 
  func(get(arg.names)) }
f1(func,arg.names = c('foo','na.rm')
```

How do I do this in a way that `get`'s all arguments from my list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try with `mget`

```
f1 <- function(func,arg.names) { 
      lst <- mget(arg.names, envir = parent.frame())
        func(lst[[1]], na.rm = lst[[2]])
 }

f1(func, arg.names = c('foo', 'na.rm'))
#[1] 3
```

---

Or another option is `do.call` (as mentioned in the @thelatemail's post) but change the `name` of the first `list` element to 'x' as `x` is the 'data' argument in the `mean` function

> ## Default S3 method:
>
> mean(x, trim = 0, na.rm = FALSE, ...)

```
 f1 <- function(func,arg.names) { 
        lst <- mget(arg.names, envir = parent.frame())
        names(lst)[1] <- 'x'
         do.call(func, lst)
     }

f1(func, arg.names = c('foo', 'na.rm'))
#[1] 3
```

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I'm looking for!  Thanks @akrun. But now the real question...is this the right (best) way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?? Or is my approach perhaps a "sloppy" or inappropriate approach?

Comment: @theforestecologist  THanks, Regarding the question, it depends on why you have to go through this route.  Perhaps you can post a new question giving more details about the final objective.

Answer (score 1):

The magic of `?do.call` awaits you:

```
do.call(func, list(foo, na.rm=na.rm))
#[1] 3
```

This essentially just creates and runs:

```
func(foo, na.rm=na.rm)
```

...where the arguments to `func` are passed in as a (potentially named) list.

Comment: what if I have to supply arguments as strings, vs the object names themselves? (e.g., 'foo' & 'na.rm' vs. foo & na.rm)

Comment: @theforestecologist - I think akrun has you covered below.